# A doubt on an answer of Wolfram.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

The matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ is a solution of the equation  $X^3=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix of order three. 
And there are another real matrices $3\text{x} 3$ such that its cube is the identity matrix, for instance, a rotation of $120^{\circ}$ in a plane having a matrix $A$ referred to a base, produces $A^3=I$ because $A^3$ becomes a rotation of $360^{\circ}$ in the considered plane. For example the rotation of  $120^{\circ}$ in the plane $\Bbb R^2$ having the matrix $A$ referred to the base $\{\vec i,\vec j\}$ equal to $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac 12&-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&-\frac 12\end{pmatrix}$$  gives by easy calculation  $A^3=I$.

Now inmersing this example in $\Bbb R^3$ one has the matrix referred to the base $\{\vec i,\vec j,\vec k\}$ as $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac 12&-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&0\\\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&-\frac 12&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ which also gives $A^3=I$. And certainly all matrix representing this rotation of $120^{\circ}$ respect to another base should have the same property.

My question is about the answer given by Wolfram|Alpha to the matrix equation $A^3=I$ with $A$ square matrix of order $3$. The answer according Wolfram is “no solutions exist”. What is the justification for this apparently wrong answer? Is it my mistake in writing the input? I have great respect for the extraordinary entity that is Wolfram|Alpha and be grateful for some explanation on this point.

[image]

Comment: There is a mathematica.stackexchange

Comment: I'd guess that you can only solve equations of the type Ax=b at the most...

Comment: @Piquito Of course but that's not a matrix equation

Comment: @Miksu: I took your comment in a general context. Wolfram does solve other algorithms with matrices.

Comment: I put the problem in a [different form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7B%7Ba,b,c%7D,%7Bd,e,f%7D,%7Bg,h,i%7D%7D%5E3+%3D+%7B%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D) and get `computation time exceeded`. Well, it is a non-trivial set of nine non-linear equations with nine unknowns.